# Регулярные выражения и перевод строки в Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Задача извлечь то, что находится на месте "body" между "begin" и "end" в приведенном ниже коде, но никак не могу понять как составить регулярное выражение, что бы оно учитывало переводы строк? В моем примере перевод строки один, но он может так же встречаться и перед "секцией" end и их может быть много и выше и ниже "body"

```
public class Appl {
public static void main(String[]    args) {
    String  source = "begin " +
            "\n"+
            " body end";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("begin(.*?)end");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
  }
}
```

**upd:** Pattern.DOTALL решает мою задачу!

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("begin(.*?)end", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: Тогда поставьте галку тому, кто ответил :) Хотя бы для того, чтобы было видно, что проблема решена.

Comment: А я сам нагуглил ответ, проапдейтил пост и увидел то, что я нагуглил в ответе. Сейчас поставлю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("begin(.*?)end", Pattern.DOTALL);
```